# tk.Tk window goes behind my Windows taskbar so there's some part of it which I cannot see

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a window of type `tk.Tk` which I start up as 'zoomed'.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

...

master = tk.Tk()

master.state('zoomed')
```

I work on a Windows laptop.

But I noticed that in that zoomed state there is a part of the Tk window which is behind my Windows OS taskbar.

How can I tell the `tk.Tk` object to fill in all my screen but without going "behind the taskbar" too i.e. I want it to fill in all the desktop space that I can actually see? The part behind the Windows taskbar I just cannot see, right?

I noticed that other program windows (e.g. Excel) do what I want (when fully zoomed). So maybe there's some option I can use to make the `tk.Tk` window do that too.

The problem is that when the Tk window is fully zoomed, there's some strip of it (behind my taskbar) which I cannot see unless I tell Windows to hide my taskbar.

Comment: For me it works as it should. When I use `zoomed` nothing goes under the taskbar. Why do you think it does this?

Comment: @DanyaK Because when I hide the taskbar, I can then see more stuff under it in the Tk window.

Comment: If you hide the taskbar, you will obviously see that window. But this is true for any apps in fully zoomed mode. For example, Excel will also cover that area if you hide a taskbar.  Hiding the taskbar will lead to the expand of the window vertically, because it will have now more space at the bottom. Maybe I don't understand something, so you can give an example that demonstrates your problem you have in a question

Comment: Are you looking for `-fullscreen` ? Have you missed that in your research?

Answer (score 0):

window.attributes('-topmost', True) this keeps the window on top
window.geometry('+50+50') this keeps it on a coordinate

Comment: This doesn't help. `window.attributes('-topmost', True)`

Comment: oh it works for me sorry